# Postgresql query to return number of customers that made more than 1 order in a month

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I have this query in my code:

```
        SELECT month, total_orders, first_orders, first_orders::numeric / total_orders::numeric * 100 AS ratio
        FROM (
          SELECT month, COUNT(1) AS total_orders
          FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('month', date) AS month, email
            FROM shop_orders
            WHERE status_code = 'CONFIRMED'
          ) AS customers
          GROUP BY month
        ) AS total_orders_my_month

        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT month, COUNT(1) AS first_orders FROM (
            SELECT email, date_trunc('month', MIN(date)) AS month
            FROM shop_orders
            WHERE status_code = 'CONFIRMED'
            GROUP BY email
          ) AS first_orders_by_month
          GROUP BY month
        ) AS first_orders_by_month2 USING (month)

        ORDER BY month DESC
```

What it does is it retursn rows in a form: month | number of customers that month | number of first time customers that month | percentage of first time customers

What I need is find for each  month also number of customers that made more then 1 order.

So I added this code:

```
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT month, COUNT(1) AS multiple_orders FROM (
            SELECT email, date_trunc('month', MIN(date)) AS month
            FROM shop_orders
            WHERE status_code = 'CONFIRMED'
            GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(1) >=2
          ) AS multiple_orders_by_month
          GROUP BY month
        ) AS multiple_orders_by_month2 USING (month)
```

This however returns only customers with 2 or more orders out of first-time customers not all customers. Can someone help please?

NOTES: All data is in shop_orders table, unique customer is identified by email field, date field has info about date of order.

I hope it's clear.

I am pretty new to postgresql so can someone point to the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would first like to point out that I am looking at this from a purely `SQL` route rather than `postsgresql` but the theory is pretty much the same. Your sub query SQL is probably overly complicated, here is my working on how I would create the query:

First, get a list of all e-mail addresses and how many orders each made that month; the following query will return the number of orders assigned to each e-mail:

```
SELECT
    month
    , email
    , COUNT(*)
FROM
    shop_orders
WHERE
    status_code = 'Confirmed'
GROUP BY
    month
    , email
```

This will return for each month the order count for each e-mail address. You can then limit this list to all e-mails which have more than one per month using the `HAVING` filter method.

```
SELECT
    month
    , email
    , COUNT(*) as ordersThisMonth
FROM
    shop_orders
WHERE
    status_code = 'Confirmed'
GROUP BY
    month
    , email
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This sub-query could then be accessed using either another aggregate such as `SUM(CASE WHEN ordersThisMonth > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` which will only count when more than one order is received. Personally I would try simplifying your query into two sub queries, one containing details which are specific to a `month`, the other for the `month` AND `email`.

(The following code has not been syntax checked and as previously mentioned I am looking at this from a purely SQL point of view.)

```
SELECT 
    month
    , total_orders
    , first_orders
    /* Add together all firstMonthCount entries as it should only be 1 for the customers first month */
    , SUM(firstMonthCount)::numeric / total_orders::numeric * 100 AS ratio
    /* Count only e-mails which have more than one order for the month */
    , SUM(CASE WHEN orderCount > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS multipleOrders
FROM 
    /*The following sub-query gets all the aggregates specific to a month */
    (   SELECT 
            date_trunc('month', date) AS month
            , COUNT(1) AS total_orders
        FROM 
            shop_orders
        WHERE 
            status_code = 'CONFIRMED'
        GROUP BY 
            month
    ) AS month_attributes
    /*The following sub-query gets all the aggregates specific to a month AND e-mail */
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            date_trunc('month', date) AS month
            , email
            , CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', date) = date_trunc('month', MIN(date)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS firstMonthCount
            , COUNT(*) AS orderCount 
        FROM 
            shop_orders
        WHERE 
            status_code = 'CONFIRMED'
        GROUP BY 
            month
            ,email
    ) AS email_month_attributes USING (month)
GROUP BY 
    month
```

Hopefully the above query and notes regarding the `HAVING` will help you find a solution that suits your purposes. I'm sure the above query could be simplified further if necessary for readability/performance.